event for all responses to slack server
Is there a way to get an event payload for all view.open/updated/closed events?
Essentially I am trying to create a custom session tracking for users who open/close a model by tracking their user_id + root_view_id once they have opened the modal. However, finding a difficult way to globally get the response from a view.open/update/closed event.
I have tried using slack_bolt.app.middleware with no use, any help is appreciated.
